# Mathematica Dashing "Up and down"

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, plot

Is there any reason that underlies mathematica's way of presenting this graph

```
ListPlot[
    Table[{x, x*01}, {x, -5, 5, .08}], 
PlotStyle -> White, 
Filling -> 0, 
FillingStyle -> {Dashed, Brown}]
```

While the dashing is present for the part of the graph above the zero boundary, another part of the graph has the filling that is solid.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: +1 because it never occurred to me to use `Dashing` for `Filling`.

Comment: What does  x*01 mean? Is that different from just x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not *that* wrong. Mathematica is interpreting your filling style as being `Dashed` below zero and `Brown` above. You just need another pair of braces, like so:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, x*01}, {x, -5, 5, .08}], PlotStyle -> White, 
 Filling -> 0, FillingStyle -> {{Dashed, Brown}}]
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually I was trying to emulate the design used in Elements of Statistical Learning (www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) (so not my idea).